# C# & ASP.NET MVC: how to remove null and empty fields from SignalR JSON response globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to remove the empty or null value from the JSON response.

I have already used in the SignalR but in this project used dependency injection.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        HubConfiguration config = new HubConfiguration()
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
        };

        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        jsonSerializer.DateFormatString = GlobalConfig.DateFormat;
        jsonSerializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => jsonSerializer);

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);
    }
}
```

But I want to use in simple 3 tier architecture ASP.NET MVC project but I can't find a proper solution.

Comment: See [NullValueSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm).

Comment: I have already seen, but how can I configure in this JSON response in the startup class

Comment: By setting the [DefaultSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm).

Comment: Yes it's helpful, but I don't want to use manually